Voltage output with enable?
It's been a long time since I've designed an electronic circuit, can someone please advise the best was to handle this problem.
I have a trigger switch as seen below, the voltage value of SPEED_CTRL should be followed by a buffer which feeds an ADC.
VCC is 3.3v
The VAR is around 20k ohm. (please advise if I need to add PU/PD on the VAR)
I would like ACTIVE_SW to also cause the output of the buffer to always be 0v when main_sw is closed otherwise the buffer output should follow SPEED_CTRL.


@Tyassin your right I can use SN74AHC1G125, thanks.

It seems you can connect ACTIVE_SW to an enable pin of a buffer, which have an active high enable. The input to the buffer should then be SPEED_CTRL.
I ended up using a buffer with output enable like this one SN74AHC1G125.

I ended up using a buffer with output enable like this one SN74AHC1G125.
